# Fixedheader jquery

Tags: jquery, css, fixed-header-tables

I'm trying to add fixedheader feature to my datatable.

I added the following statement: `new FixedHeader( oTable);`

```
oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable({ 
    "aaSorting": [ [0,'asc'] ], "aoColumns" : dataTableColumns, "oLanguage": {   
        "sLengthMenu": 'Show <select>'+ 
                       '<option value="10">10<\/option>'+ 
                       '<option value="25">25<\/option>'+ 
                       '<option value="50">50<\/option>'+ 
                       '<option value="100">100<\/option>'+ 
                       '<option value="-1">All<\/option>'+
                       '<\/select> records' }, "iDisplayLength": -1, }); 
new FixedHeader( oTable);
```

A floating header got created on top of the original header. The header had transparent background with a font and style different from my existing header. It looks very odd when the floating header overlaps on the current header.

CSS code:

```
table.display thead th {
    padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
}

table.display tfoot th {
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.display tr.heading2 td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so far. It's very difficult to assist without it. Also - please reference the plugin you're using for the fixed header if applicable..

Comment: I'm using FixedHeader.js   Here is my datatable code:

Comment: `oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable({
     "aaSorting": [ [0,'asc'] ],
   "aoColumns" : dataTableColumns,
   "oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": 'Show <select>'+
     '<option value="10">10<\/option>'+
     '<option value="25">25<\/option>'+
     '<option value="50">50<\/option>'+
     '<option value="100">100<\/option>'+
     '<option value="-1">All<\/option>'+
     '<\/select> records'
   },
   "iDisplayLength": -1,
    });
  new FixedHeader( oTable);`

Comment: THanks for posting. It may be better to use the `edit` feature to add this code to the original question, where it can be formatted rather than the comments. If you have existing CSS styles those would also help. There may not be enough information right now to know where the problem lies, but it sounds like a styling issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here's the CSS style: Is there a way I can set style to the floating header?  `table.display thead th {
 padding: 3px 18px 3px 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 * cursor: hand;
}

table.display tfoot th {
 padding: 3px 10px;
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 font-weight: bold;
}

table.display tr.heading2 td {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
`

Comment: This is fixed.. added CSS style - .FixedHeader_Cloned th to match the existing header.